# mysql harddrive efficiency with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a program that receives about 20 arbitrary measurements per second from some source. Each measurement has a type, timestamp, min, avg, and max value. I then need to create up to X aggregates of each measurement type.

The program can be set up with 100s of sources at the same time, this results in a lot of data that I need to store quickly and retrieve quickly.

The system that this will run on has no memory/storage/cpu limitations, but there is another service on there that is writing to the hdd at almost the limit of the its capability. For this question, let's assume that this is a "top of the line" HDD and I won't be able to upgrade to a hdd.

What I'm doing right now is generating a table per measurement type (20x source) with partitioning along the timestamp value of each measurement as new measurement types are encountered. I'm doing this so as not to fragment the measurement data across the HDD which will allow me to insert or query data with a minimum amount of 'seeking.'

Does this make sense? I have no need of doing any joins or complex queries, it's all either a straight-forward batch-inserts or a single measurement type query by a timestamp range.

How does MySql store the data in the tables across the HDD? How can I better design the DB to minimize the HDD seek during insert & query?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking general questions which can be discovered by reading the documentation or browsing knowledgebase articles by using google or whatever search engine that you prefer.  If you are using the MyISAM engine, which is the default then each table is stored as three files in a db-specific directory, with the big ones being the MYD file for the row-data and the MYI file for all of the indexes.

The most important thing that you can do is to get you configuration parameters correct so that it can optimise access and caching.  MySQL will do a better job than you can realistically expect to do.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html for more info and compare the settings for the my-small.cnf and my-large.cnf that you will find on your system as this section discusses.